# Rendering collections of heterogeneous objects in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Lets say my app has 3 main types of objects the user interacts with: pictures, videos, and "tweets". I have no problem rendering a collection of any one object type or even all three as separate lists:

```
<% @pictures.each do |picture| %>
  <%= picture.name %>
  <%= img_tag(picture.url) %>
<% end %>

<% @tweets.each do |tweet| %>
  <%= tweet.message %>
<% end %>

<% @videos.each do |video| %>
  <%= video.title %>
  <%= video.thumbnail %>
<% end %>
```

What I would like to do is render a single "feed" that consists of all three different object types intermixed in chronological order.

### Possible Solutions:

I've seen solutions such as creating an entirely new db table called something like "activity_feed" that has a polymorphic association to all other models and records an entry for every object added to the db. This seems inefficient and overkill for what I'm trying to accomplish. Theres also the "public_activity" gem, which does the same thing.

I've been messing with querying each collection individually, then combining the collections and sorting in ruby, but am having trouble sorting active record objects.

```
@feed_items = @pictures + @videos + @tweets
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to query and sort this all from the db layer for performance reasons. (I'm using Postgres!)

I'm new to rails and coding in general. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You definitely don't need to change your db schema just to _render_ a list of hetereogenous items. But you may if you need to _query_ or _sort_ the hetereogenous list, if you need to ask for "The 10 latest picture/video/tweeks".  If your situation makes it okay to _query_ them separately, as you say, but then sort them together -- this is actually pretty easy. And displaying them is easy. But if three separate queries isn't going to work, that will require db schema changes of some kind, of which you have a few options. So first step is thinking through your requirements.

Comment: @jrochkind db schema changes as in keeping all columns consistent between tables for the 3 object types? I'm unclear on how one would go about querying different data types in a single query if it all has to fit into a single consolidated output table. Perhaps the three object types could all inherit from another class and the query could be for objects of that class?

Comment: Hope you will get the idea of how to do it.

Comment: Yes, if you need to get all three kinds of output, sorted together, in a single query -- you'll have to make some changes to your db. That's what I mean by 'db schema changes', just changes to how your data is stored in your db, one way or another. You have several options, including using ActiveRecord inheritance functions. If you are okay with making three separate queries and combining the results programmatically -- then it's much simpler and straightforward. It depends on what kind of query(ies) you need to make. eg "Most recent 10 of all combined objects" will require db changes.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make an activity_feed model and then add items to the activity feed model and then query and display the activity feed model versus querying multiple models. Then you can sort on this anyway you want.

```
def create
   if @comment.save
     ActivityFeed.create(...)
   end
end
```

Then when you want to display the feed just display it.

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/using-polymorphism-to-make-a-better-activity-feed-in-rails

There are activity feed gems that help with this if you don't want to make it from scratch.

https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity

https://github.com/GetStream/stream-rails

Comment: Not looking for shortcuts here. I'm a beginner trying to do things right the first time. 

By design this method requires duplicate data. A user posts a picture. Data for that picture is stored in the pictures table such as when it was posted and by whom. An additional activity feed table would refer to that picture in the pictures table and also record when the picture was posted and by whom. This seems excessive to me - not in the amount of work it will require to implement, but in terms of data table entries. Perhaps the problems I'm running into are why so many people choose this route.

Comment: You see it as duplicate data, but it's not. Your application has the requirement of an activity feed. There is something called the "SRP Single Responsibility Principle" which good developers follow. You need a class which has the sole responsibility of being the activity feed. Push what information you need to display into the activity feed. What you don't see right now is what you want to build on top of the activity feed once it's working.... Your way will have built yourself into a corner. Making it an activity feed gives you endless possibilities.